# A young woman's old husband is taken away by a crocodile

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, semantics, idiom-meaning

> **A  young woman 's  going  for  an ablution in the Ganges with  her  fellow women resulted  in her  old husband  being  taken away  by  a  crocodile**

*Telugu:  Satt varito  sariganga snanalu  chestunte , musali  moginni musali yettuku  poindi*

It is  beaiful for its  assonance  and meaning.

*The  context:  It  is  a  custom among  the  Hindus  to  have  a  holy  dip  in the  river  duriing  Pushkaras ( every 12 years) and  during some festive  seasons. It  is  a  custom that  both  wife  and  husband have  a dip   in the  rivers  at the  same time  along  with  some  others  couples. While  a  young  woman and  her old  husband along with  some  other  couples  were  taking the  holy dips , a crocodile  took  the  old man away causing  the  young  woman a lot  of  agony. ( The  practice  of  taking  the  bath  by  a number  of  couples  is  called   **sariganga snanalu** ( taking  a bath  together  by  wife arnd husband  in the rivers)*     **( It  is not a  tale. The  people  in My  region  understand  the  idiom  without  any  context.  ,  in  fact  it  is  not  a tale  or 
 something  really  happened )**

This  proverb  is  used  in a humorous  context  to  say  that  if  we  try  to  imitate  others  without  knowing  our  limitations, we  might  find  ourselves  in real trouble..

I would  like  to  know  a  similar  and  funny  proverb in English.

Comment: One frequently used idiom is to say something like "If you do that (eg. go for a dip in the Ganges) ***you may get more than you bargain for***..."

Comment: @ WSz.What  you  say is  correct and  it  is  a phrase.Mine  is  an idiom used in a  humorous  context  but  with  a  moral.

Comment: There's no guarantee that there'll be a satisfying corresponding idiom. "Biting off more than you can chew" is close though.

Comment: The beauty of tales from particular places or societies like this often lies in their special uniqueness.  This one is beautifully subtle.  It plays on the weakness and predictability of men.  Present them with an opportunity for surreptitious voyeurism and thoughts of the riverside's dangers fly out of the window.  thank you for a wonderful proverb,  Nothing I know of can match it.

Comment: I'm missing the intended subtext here.  Why was the old husband near the river?  Ostensibly to watch over his young wife? To gawk at all the other women washing themselves? Is it saying he intended to be the "crocodile" preying on all the women and in a turn of events gets preyed upon by a real croc?   Is that (a crocodile) what he was imitating?

Comment: @Jim.I edited  my  post  so  that  those  readers   like 
you  who  do not  know  the  context , understand  the  joke  and  the  moral  now  because  of  the  explanation

Comment: [young's woman going for an ablution in the Ganges: buzzer. And: the practice of bathing, perhaps, but not having a bath] This is a **wonderful folk tale**, not a proverb. A proverb would be: Bathing in rivers gives crocodiles their appetite.

Comment: @  Lambie :  No. It  is  an  Idiom. The  tale  is  narrated  by  me.The  Indians  or  at least  the  people  of  South  India  can  imagine  the  context  on  hearing the  idiom.It  is  not  at  all  a tale.

Comment: I still don't understand the joke. You say the incident caused the wife 'agony', so it wasn't that  she was glad to be rid of her elderly husband. Do you mean that he was foolish to go in the river because if his age?

Comment: @ I  do  not  understand  why  you  think  that  the  young  woman  happy. Does  agony mean  happy?  It  is  a  joke  for  others  who  make the  comment  but  not  for  her.

Comment: @Englishmonger - Thanks for the explanation, but I still don't get it.  A couple goes for their 12-year communal holy dip and the husband gets eaten by a crocodile.  I don't see any imitation involved. And who didn't know their limitations?  Are you saying the old man was foolish to try to bathe in the river at his age?  But surely people in a river are pretty much equally vulnerable to crocodiles.  They're all equally foolish for going in while crocs are present-  that the man got eaten was pure luck for the others.  The English expression "But for the grace of God go I" comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't try this at home.**

It's a homily, grading into a platitude, rather than a proverb; I've seen it used in parody when some impossible feat, simulated by special effects, is shown on TV or at the cinema.

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Don%27t%20try%20this%20at%20home) (slightly amended) gives the original usage:

> *Don't try this at home.*
>
> Phrase often used in TV shows. When people in them do stupid,
>   dangerous or crazy things and show them to millions of people, and
>   they don't want to be responsible for injuries, deaths or any
>   consequences that could happen to the audience.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation of the proverb brings to mind something that I (and probably a lot of other U.S. children) heard frequently when I tried to justify my actions to various adults with "All of my friends are doing it", which is:

> If all of your friends jumped off of a bridge, would you jump too?

It's not a proverb, but I think the meaning is the same.